# django object is not iterable using serializers.serialize

Tags: django

I'm getting the following error,

**Template' object is not iterable**

```
def get_AJAX(request, id):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", Template.objects.get(pk=id))
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

However, I'm using `'get'` so I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Serialize a single object?

Comment: @Paulo Bu, yes, when this is a list it works but with 1 object I get the error.

Answer (score 27):

That's because you're not passing an [iterable nor a QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/), you're passing instead a `Template` object. If you want to serialize that single object you can do it like this:

```
def get_AJAX(request, id):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", [Template.objects.get(pk=id)])
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

**UPDATE:** Recommending using `filter` instead.

Also consider using `filter` instead of get in order to avoid possible exceptions if pk doesn't exists. This way you don't need the brackets because it is a `QuerySet` object

```
def get_AJAX(request, id):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", Template.objects.filter(pk=id))
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: but this still outputs json as an array not as an object.

Answer (score 1):

Following Paulo Bu Example. Sometimes we'd like to use get due it offers other functionalities like get_object_or_404(), this function uses get under the hood, so a little workaround is to enclosed the object in a list.

```
def get_AJAX(request, id):
    _data = [Template.objects.get(pk=id)] # This is now list.
    data = serializers.serialize("json", _data)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

or

```
def get_AJAX(request, id):
    _data = [get_object_or_404(Template, pk=id)] # This is now list.
    data = serializers.serialize("json", _data)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an Object without it being in a List, just simply do this :

```
serializer = CustomSerializerClass(queryset) # This queryset is the one with a get()

return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, data=serializer.data)
```

**Note :**

You don't need to add `many=True` in the serializer :

```
serializer = CustomSerializerClass(queryset)
```